# MCPE GLSL Conditionals

Tags: opengl-es, conditional-statements, glsl

I'm writing an ios vertex shader that "flattens" a MC world in the x direction if a change in the z direction is detected, and vice versa (The xz plane is perp to height). I have several shaders that warp the world just fine, but writing this pseudo movement detection hasn't worked. I know conditionals are costly. I was comparing the position to a number and it worked:

```
if (worldPos.x != 4.) {
    worldPos.z = 0.;
}
```

But comparing position to a static call of the position doesn't. So far I've tried assigning constant floats to the x and z components, uniform floats, and a POS4 uniform, but no success. I have a feeling the conditionals fail because of a data type problem? It would be easier to debug if PE version displayed coord like PC. Thanks for any/all help! Current code:

```
uniform POS4 CHUNK_ORIGIN_AND_SCALE;
attribute POS4 POSITION;

void main()
{

POS4 worldPos;
worldPos.xyz = (POSITION.xyz * CHUNK_ORIGIN_AND_SCALE.w) + CHUNK_ORIGIN_AND_SCALE.xyz;
worldPos.w = 1.;
const float staticPosx = worldPos.x;
const float staticPosz = worldPos.z;

if (worldPos.x != staticPosx) {
    worldPos.z = 0.;
    staticPosx = worldPos.x;
}

if (worldPos.z != staticPosz) {
    worldPos.x = 0.;
    staticPosz = worldPos.z;
}

etc.
```

Comment: What is a `POS4`? That's not part of GLSL. Also, what is an "MC world"?

Comment: @NicolBolas `POS4` is x,y,z and a size factor w. It might only be used for OpenGL. MCPE is Minecraft Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't try it in glsl but in C you can't

```
int a=5;
const int b=a;
```